# Modelling explicitly lower and upper bound in summation

Tags: pyomo

I have a problem modelling the following linked sum with `Pyomo`.

[Sum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0oGa.jpg)

Notation:

```
Index s: periods

dt_f: Parameter

X^{FD}_{f,s}: Variable
```

Normally, I would use for instance

```
sum((model.XFD[f,s])/(model.dt[f]) for f in model.F).
```

However, this is not possible in this case, because I just want to sum up over last `dt_f` periods. Is there a possibility to define the lower and upper bound in a sum explicitly, instead of summing up over all elements?